# Fluent NHibernate mapping inheritance

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Can I have map a abstract class even the object doesn´t exists in my database?

Example:

```
public abstract class Type
{
  public string Id{get; set;}
}
```

And the subs:

```
public class TypeA : Type
{
}

public class TypeB : Type
{
}
```

A class who needs the reference to base class:

```
public class Other
{
  public Type MyType{get; set;}
}
```

The Type doesn´t exists in my database, but I need this map to references in other classes, how I can map this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I´ll let the abstract class like a "fake" map, for now my problem is resolved.
Thanks.